# gamma or curves in KineticJS

Tags: html, image-processing, canvas, kineticjs

Is it possible to modify image gamma or curves using KineticJS? I need those tools to modify canvas. The documentation says nothing about that (see [Filters](http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Filters.html)), but maybe I can do it not directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, KineticJS does not currently have a Gamma filter.

You have a couple of good workarounds:

**Option#1**

If you are familiar with creating filters, you can fairly easily add a gamma filter to KineticJS.

The existing KineticJS filters just do getImageData+putImageData to directly modify the pixels: https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/tree/master/src/filters

**Option#2**

CamanJS is a canvas image library that does a nice job of applying filters: 
http://camanjs.com/examples/

You can easily use CamanJS with KineticJS as described in my previous answer:  [KineticJS canvas modified by CamanJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21549832/kineticjs-canvas-modified-by-camanjs)