# How can I transform a CamanJS Filter into a KineticJS Filter?

Tags: javascript, html, kineticjs, camanjs

From [CamanJS](https://github.com/meltingice/CamanJS/blob/master/dist/caman.full.js) given the following filter:

```
Caman.Filter.register("lomo", function(vignette) {
    if (vignette == null) {
      vignette = true;
    }
    this.brightness(15);
    this.exposure(15);
    this.curves('rgb', [0, 0], [200, 0], [155, 255], [255, 255]);
    this.saturation(-20);
    this.gamma(1.8);
    if (vignette) {
      this.vignette("50%", 60);
    }
    return this.brightness(5);
  });
```

**How can I transform this filter into a [KineticJS](http://kineticjs.com/) equivalent?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CamanJS and KineticJS filters are achieved very differently.

KineticJS filters manipulate pixel data in a single pass.

CamanJS uses subsystems that change the image incrementally (subsystems==this.brightness, this.exposure, etc).

**Therefore, there is no simple way to convert a CamanJS filter into a KineticJS filter**

To do it you would have to refactor and embed many CamanJS subsystems into KineticJS.

You could do that since both CamanJS and KineticJS are open source with liberal licensing, but it would mean refactoring and adding at least the following subsystems (and their dependencies) into KineticJS from CamanJSs: https://github.com/meltingice/CamanJS/blob/master/dist/caman.full.js

- brightness,
- exposure,
- curves,
- saturation,
- gamma

Perhaps a better idea would be to apply your filter using CamanJS on an in-memory canvas.  Then you could use that in-memory canvas as an image source for a Kinetic.Image.  Here's a link on how to do that: [KineticJS canvas modified by CamanJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21549832/kineticjs-canvas-modified-by-camanjs/21562940#21562940)

Comment: I can't use CamanJS to modify the canvas because I work on mobile. On mobile CamanJS is very slow and I would say unusable.

Comment: Fair enough, then you can certainly pull the necessary guts out of CamanJS for use in KineticJS.  Without knowing, I suspect the performance gains will be relatively small compared to actually using CamanJS because you are making multiple passes at the pixel array.  Your best bet would be to combine all the CamanJS subsystem processing into a single pass. So your lomo would merge the pixel manipulations done by CamanJS brightness, exposure, curves, saturation & gamma subsystems into a single modification of the pixel array. Good luck with your project!

Comment: How can I combine all these things into a single pass?

Comment: Each of the CamanJS subsystems is really just an algebraic formula. So you just combine all those formulae into a single equation and apply that 1 equation to each pixel in your pixel data array. So brightness is `data[n]+Math.floor(255*(brightness/100));` and gamma is `Math.pow(data[n]/255),gammaFactor)*255;` so the single combined formula for brightness and gamma is `Math.pow((data[n]+Math.floor(255*(brightness/100)))/255),gammaFactor)*255;`. So you would similarly combine the brightness, exposure, curves, saturation & gamma equations into 1 equation-set that's applied to `getImageData`.